# Azure Data factory CI/CD

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-factory

I have my `ADF` files built using Visual studio and need to build continuous deployment for this using `VSTS`..I have my `ADF` files and PowerShell in a single solution. But in my PowerShell script how can I refer the `ADF` files. What should be the path instead of `C:/users/`. Where I can find this path in my build. Hope this is clear

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem "C:/users/" -filter "*LinkedService*")
{
  New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService -ResourceGroupName "ADFAutomationResource" -DataFactoryName "ADFCICD190218" -Name $file.BaseName -File $file.FullName -Force | Format-List
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your build, in the "Copy and Publish Build Artifacts" step, add the data factory folder like this: 
`**\DataFactoryFolder\*.json`

In your release you can pass the folder location to your PowerShell script by using the following variable:

`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/DataFactory`